Is it a bad idea to stream a download, from azure storage, through an azure web app to an end-user?
Is it a bad idea to stream a download, from azure storage, through an azure web app to an end-user? The web application is a C# aspnet core api application hosted on azure web app services.
As opposed to just directly from storage with an SAS token, which is what we do currently. Our web application, which is a JS react app, is given the Azure Storage link to the file, with SAS token attached, and the user can clearly see and copy that download link.
I'm brainstorming ways to hide this storage download url from users, even if it has the SAS token. A client didn't like the fact that this url could be copied and shared and used without additional authentication.
We do not user Azure Entra ID yet for auth. We use a self hosted IdentityServer4 auth web application. So I don't think I can authenticate right on AZ Storage, aside from SAS tokens.

"Is it a bad idea to stream a download, from azure storage, through an azure web app to an end-user?" - Yes.  It is very inefficient and will make downloads slow.

A client didn't like the fact that this url could be copied and shared and used without additional authentication. That would be a deliberate action, as deliberate as uploading the downloaded file an a public accessible place. Its the same risk. Some advice: make sure the SAS token has a very limited expiration time and that it can only be used for reading that specific blob. Even if the SAS token is leaked or shared it can't be used to access the blob if it is already expired.


Is it a bad idea to stream a download, from azure storage, through an azure web app to an end-user?

I agree with both Stephen C 's and Peter Bons 's comment
Yes, it will make slow download and streaming large files through your web app is inefficient.
Streaming files through your web app is an effective solution for hiding URLs and making more cautious, but it can impact performance and scalability. Direct SAS token access to storage is faster and more scalable.
You can generate short span of time of sas token with limited permission scope to avoid leakage.
Here is the code to generate sas token with minimal permission.
public string GenerateSasToken(string containerName, string blobName, int expiryMinutes)
{
    var containerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

    var sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder
    {
        BlobContainerName = containerName,
        BlobName = blobName,
        Resource = "b",  //blob
        ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(expiryMinutes)
    };

    sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read);  // Only read permission
    return blobClient.GenerateSasUri(sasBuilder).ToString();
}

Also, you can try with Azure Front Door or an Azure CDN provide signed URLs that are user-specific and short-lived.
Reference:

Quickstart: Integrate an Azure Storage account with Azure Content Delivery Network | Microsoft Learn
Integrate an Azure Storage account with Azure Front Door - Azure Front Door | Microsoft Learn

